# How can I get request data in Django from a redirect?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-request

I need to get data from a redirect, but I can't really figure out how. The method is GET as I can see from my print. But I have tried everything I found on searching for this without luck.
What am I doing wrong? I really appreciate any help.

I have this redirect:

```
return redirect('/list-view', new = 'new')
```

My urls looks like this:

```
path('list-view/<new>', views.list_view, name='list'),
```

Then my list-view is:

```
def list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
  print(request.method)
  if request.method == 'GET':
      aa=request.GET.get('new')
      if aa:
          bb = (request.GET.get('new'))
          print (bb['new'])
```

Comment: I think ```return redirect()``` wiil put arguments in your ```urls``` and not sending back list of items for showing in template. Do you need to pass arguments to ```urls``` only ?

Comment: I really don't care how the values are sent as long as I can get them in my next view. It is just a parameter telling me if it is a new product or not. Do you have a better idea to send data so please let me know. :-)

Comment: Actually, you gave me an idea that works.
    return redirect('/list-view?new=new')

Answer (score 1):

If you define a parameter in the url, like you are doing, you can actually put it as a input on the view function,

```py
def list_view(request, new):
  # ...
```

BTW to use the name you need to reverse it, something like this,

```py
new = True
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list', args=(new,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the URL instead of the absolute path. `return redirect('list', new = 'new')`

Comment: Is the parameters not added to the url that way?

Comment: In your way or mine ?